# Transmission for constant-speed, variable-torque output from variable-speed, variable-torque input?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm interested in designing a transmission to achieve a constant-speed, variable-torque output from variable-speed, variable-torque input -- something like a CVT, but applied backward. Is such a thing possible? Do any examples of a transmission like this exist commonly?

I'm happy to answer any clarifying questions, as I'm imagining this doesn't include all the needed information. Thank you in advance for your patience!

EDIT: I should mention that the specific effect that I'm looking for is that when the input speed increases, the output speed remains constant, but the output *torque* increases proportionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an early solution to air conditioning of railroad cars the variable-speed motion of the axles was transmitted through such a coupling to provide constant speed drive for the A/C compressor. There are several mechanical and electromechanical CVT type mechanisms that could be used.

To find information about the various CVT technologies, you should also search "mechanical adjustable-speed drive" and "mechanical variable-speed drive." The term CVT is primarily used for vehicle components. The ASD and VSD terms are used with industrial equipment. In industry, electrical equipment is usually used, but there are mechanical alternatives. Note that descriptions of the equipment that you find will be be the direction opposite to what you want, but the reverse alternative can usually be achieved with the same or similar equipment.

> EDIT: I should mention that the specific effect that I'm looking for is that when the input speed increases, the output speed remains constant, but the output torque increases proportionally.

You can regulate speed or you can regulate torque, but you can not regulate both simultaneously. The characteristics of the load must dictate one or the other. Perhaps you should explain the system more completely and add a diagram.

Comment: One point of specificity that I'd neglected to mention is that as the variable-speed input increases, the output speed should stay the same, but the output torque should _increase_. Do you have any recommendations on mechanisms to address that requirement? I may simply be misunderstanding the capabilities of ASDs/VSDs.

Comment: I'm just trying to regulate speed, not torque. I was assuming that, by regulating speed, I'd see somewhat proportional increases in torque using a mechanism like the one you suggested. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you regulate speed, the torque transmitted to the load will be whatever it takes to drive the load at the speed you select. If the drive doesn't have the capability to produce enough torque to drive the load at the selected speed, regulation will fail and the drive will either operate at a lower speed than selected or malfunction in some manner. The torque vs speed capability of the drive will vary according to the specific technology selected.

Comment: The torque capability of the drive setup will be determined by the characteristics of the CVT and whatever is driving the CVT. To some extent, the best choice of CVF technology will depend on the torque vs speed capability characteristics of whatever is driving the CVT. With the proper choice of CVT, you can get increased torque capability with increased input speed.